# Is draw-order important for synced zoom over muliple charts? (or: Why do strange thing happen only in certain order)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to syncronize a zoom over 3 different svg containers that only zooms x in the latest d3. However I'm running in some problem when drawing the charts in a certain order and I can't find the reason for it happening.

As you can see in the snippet below, if I draw the charts in a specific order, somehow the path (and only the path) of the first drawn chart scales the y. The other 2 charts remain normal.

If I change the order the charts everything zooms in like expected.

There are no errors in the console so I must be missing something.

```js
chart_collection = {
  'chart1': null,
  'chart2': null,
  'chart3': null
}
data1 = [{"Zeit": 1545133336890.0, "Wert": 0.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133751410.0, "Wert": 1.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133751536.0, "Wert": 0.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133763825.0, "Wert": 1.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133763952.0, "Wert": 0.0}];
data2 = [{"Zeit": 1545133336890.0, "Wert": 0.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133753262.0, "Wert": 1.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133753443.0, "Wert": 0.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133765675.0, "Wert": 1.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133765851.0, "Wert": 0.0}];
data3 = [{"Zeit": 1545133336890.0, "Wert": 0.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133704869.0, "Wert": 16.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133704922.0, "Wert": 0.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133706487.0, "Wert": 1.0}, {"Zeit": 1545133881674.0, "Wert": 33.0}];


/* Only bugged when firstChart is really drawn first */
drawChart(data3, 'firstChart', 'chart3');
drawChart(data1, 'anotherChart', 'chart1');
drawChart(data2, 'YetAnotherChart', 'chart2');

function drawChart(data, name, type) {
  width = document.getElementById("info").offsetWidth;
  height = 100;

  /* Scales and Line-Generators */
  x = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.Zeit;
    }));

  y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return d.Wert;
    }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.Wert;
    })]);

  binaryY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

  binaryLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.Zeit)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return binaryY(d.Wert)
    })
    .curve(d3.curveStepBefore);

  nonBinaryLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.Zeit)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.Wert)
    });

  /* Start of drawing */
  var svg = d3.select('#' + type)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('class', 'chart');

  var canvas = svg.append("g");

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .translateExtent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  if (type == 'chart3') {
    canvas.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'graphs')
      .selectAll(name)
      .data([data])
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', name)
      .attr('d', nonBinaryLine)
      .attr('stroke-width', '1')
      .attr('stroke', 'blue')
      .attr('fill', 'none');
  } else {
    canvas.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'graphs')
      .selectAll(name)
      .data([data])
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', name)
      .attr('d', binaryLine)
      .attr('stroke-width', '1')
      .attr('stroke', 'blue')
      .attr('fill', 'none');
  }

  canvas.append("svg:rect")
    .attr('opacity', 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  canvas.call(zoom);

  chart_collection[type] = svg;

}

function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform,
    xt = t.rescaleX(x);

  binaryLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xt(d.Zeit)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return binaryY(d.Wert)
    })
    .curve(d3.curveStepBefore);

  nonBinaryLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xt(d.Zeit)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.Wert)
    });

  if (chart_collection['chart3']) {
    changeZoom(nonBinaryLine, 'chart3', xt);
  }
  if (chart_collection['chart1']) {
    changeZoom(binaryLine, 'chart1', xt);
  }
  if (chart_collection['chart2']) {
    changeZoom(binaryLine, 'chart2', xt);
  }

}

function changeZoom(lineGenerator, chart, zoomArea) {
  chart_collection[chart].select('.xAxis')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(zoomArea));
  chart_collection[chart].select('.graphs')
    .selectAll('path')
    .attr("d", lineGenerator);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mini-Demo</title>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="info">
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <div id="chart2"></div>
    <div id="chart3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried making the snippet as small as possible. It still is quite a load of code because of the charts that have to be drawn and the handmade zoom.

Comment: the variable `x` in your code is an implicit global that gets a new value assigned each time you call `drawChart()`. Later this value is used for scaling the x axis. Is this the case in you original code as well?

Comment: @line-o Ye sit is the same in the original. Mainly because I don't know how else I can sync the scales for all charts.